# Local variables in DynamicModule affected by outside evaluation

Tags: dynamic, inputfield

I was trying to use `DynamicModule` to create a `Input` cell that contains a variable assignment, where the variable name is given by a `InputField`. A minimal example is:

```
createExample[] := DynamicModule[{name = Null},
  Column[{
    InputField[Dynamic[name]],
    Button["OK",
     With[{name1 = name},
      CellPrint[ExpressionCell[
        Defer[name1 = 99999]
        , "Input"]]]
     ]
    }]
  ]
```

Running `createExample[]` will give

[image: 1]

Enter a variable name called `var1` and click OK button
[image: 2]

However, when I evaluate this assignment, the `InputField` also changes
[image: 3]

My question is, how to avoid the change of the variable inside the `DynamicModule`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you work with [`Boxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boxes) you don't have to worry about evaluations:

```
createExample[] := DynamicModule[{name=""},
    Column[{
        InputField[Dynamic[name],Boxes, ContinuousAction->True],
        Button[
            "OK",
            Dynamic @ CellPrint[Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{name, "=", "99999"}]], "Input"]]
        ]
    }]
]
```

A short animation:

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks! this is exactly what I want. But I'm still curious how could global variable get into the `DynamicModule` in my version or if there is any caveat of using `DynamicModule`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a different way to inject the value of `name` into the cell:

```
createExample[] := DynamicModule[{name = Null},
  Column[{
    InputField[Dynamic[name], Hold[Expression]],
    Button["OK", 
     name /. Hold[v_] :> CellPrint[ExpressionCell[Defer[v = 99999], "Input"]]]
    }]
  ]
```

The reason `var1` becomes `99999` in the OP's code is that the displayed content of the `InputField` is the dynamically updated value of `name`.  When `name` is set to `var1`, it displays the value of `var1`.  Initially, it has no value, so we see `var1` displayed.  But when a value for `var1` is set, the value is displayed.  The above prevents that by specifying the type of the contents to be a held expression. "Held" means that it won't be evaluated.  It also means that the value of `name` will be `Hold[var1]` when `var1` is entered into the field.  To handle this, I opted for the alternative method of injecting the user's input into the `Set` command in the cell.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: @L.Yu You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

In your code name1 is not localised within the scope of the DynamicModule. Try your experiments on these two variations.

```
 createExample2[] := 
 DynamicModule[{name = Null}, 
 Column[{Dynamic@name1, InputField[Dynamic[name]],
 Button["OK", With[{name1 = name}, 
   CellPrint[ExpressionCell[Defer[name1 = 99999], "Input"]]]]}]];

 createExample3[]:=DynamicModule[{name = Null, name1}, 
 Column[{Dynamic@name1, InputField[Dynamic[name]],
 Button["OK", With[{name1 = name}, 
  CellPrint[ExpressionCell[Defer[name1 = 99999], "Input"]]]]}]];
```

Comment: These two works the same as mine... Did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, In createExample3 name1 is now not a global variable so you can't alter it outside of DynamicModule.